# Amortization table in matlab

Tags: matlab, printf

How can I use fprintf to build an amortization table in Matlab?
Right now, to get a table, I'm using:

```
tab=[[0:Nm]',Balance',Interest',Principal',];
disp(['          ','Month','      ','Balance','        ','Interest','     ','Principal'])
disp (tab)
```

The table looks okay as is, but I'm told I need to do it with the fprintf command.

Comment: `fprintf` is a very common function that is present in many programming languages its definitely worth learning how to use it. I suggest starting with google or `help fprintf` both will provide you with what you need to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that you could not have found this from [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html), but here goes:

```
clc

fprintf('%12s %12s %12s %12s\n', ...
    'Month', 'Balance', 'Interest', 'Principal')

format bank
for ii = 1:numel(Balance)
    fprintf('%12d %12.2f %12.2f %12.2f\n', ...
        ii, Balance(ii), Interest(ii), Principal(ii));

end
```